# How to build the webRTC framework for tvOS?

Tags: ios, swift3, webrtc, voip, tvos

I have been trying to figure out how the library can be generated for tvOS. 
I was able to generate a framework following this link https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/

After which I read up more about how does this library works.

I have searched on many websites currently openTok provides their own sdk for tvOS.. 
Can anyone help me in this situation I want to generate the library for tvOS.

Comment: Take a look at this link [WebRTC for tvOS](https://gist.github.com/kapejod/d99ec6e6ce206bd584055ec75ad63740) as it seems there is modification needed and as the guy it might not work anymore

Comment: Thanks a lot man! i'll definitely try this thing out..

Comment: Is there any example like appRTC is for ios.

Comment: after downloading the WebRTC source code do the changes as on the link try compiling with different architectures

Comment: Okay.. Thanks! i'll keep you posted with the updates..

Comment: The webrtc code has changed so the changes made as shown in the link fails to create a framework also I am using gn instead of gyp to build the framework as mentioned here : https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/

Comment: I see, please be sure to make the correct changes on the correct file and using the correct architectures for tvOS. And try using suggested build tools that you currently use.

Comment: Hi, I know it's late, but did you manage to make a tvOS build? if so, how? Thank you.